# Can you pass pointers to iterators of a std::vector

Tags: c++, qt, vector, c++98

I came across the following code and it raised some questions in my head

```
std::vector<unsigned char> buf(bytes.constData(), bytes.constData() + bytes.size());
```

where  `bytes is QByteArray` and `bytes.constData()` returns `const char*`

I went over the constructor of the vector [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) and the only constructor that I think fits for this description is

```
 vector (InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
                 const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

Now my question is:

1-Is it possible to pass a pointer to an iterator of a vector ?  and why is it `bytes.constData() + bytes.size()`  ? Does this make a copy for instance if we later made changes to bytes would it affect buf ?

Comment: See the example here. It says that the constructor can accept array as an input. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"An iterator of a vector" is misguided here: the vector constructor in question is a template and accepts *any* iterator. That's the whole point -- you can construct the container from any iterable range.

And pointers *are* indeed iterators. In fact, the entire concept of iterators is basically a generalization of the notion of a "pointer".

The vector constructor copies the data from the input range, so later changes to `bytes` will not affect the vector.